# Disable booting into bios

Tags: boot, bios, reboot

I have a remote computer, which I am connecting to. From time to time, it reboots itself (it's sort of control mechanism if something goes wrong - I can't change this). It's ok that it restarts itself, problem is that sometimes, it won't boot into Windows, and goes to bios screen or bios boot scren. Is it possible to avoid this?

Comment: What can you tell us about why it is doing that? Does it show any information that indicates any sort of problem?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what error message the bios hangs on ?
I've managed servers in the past that hung on "silly" things such as "no keyboard connected", which seeing how it is a server; is a rather normal thing.

Most errors can be suppressed through altering BIOS settings.
The setting you are looking for is called "Halt on" or "Halt on Error" in most bios interfaces.

example
http://www.nastrojkabios.ru/images/stories/bios/1/Halt-On-2.jpg

Some errors like memory issues cannot always be suppressed and not all bios types allow you to do so.

Hope it helps!